# How to handle large amount of load with node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

My node.js server will handle 50k simultaneous clients. An single node.js server isn't able to handle such amount of load. I suppose to setup 5 or 10 node.js server running on different ports. And, have a load-balancer, e.g. Nginx, listening to each node.js server. When one server reach 10k clients, route the excess coming-in connections to other node.js servers. Is this the right way to handle such load with node.js? If not, what's the best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple way to handle the load is indeed to use a load balancer to forward the requests to different server on the same machine or on remote machines.

If you would to setup the servers only on one machine, use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), it will take care of the load balancing and keeping your server instances alive.

**Be aware** that running on one machine doesn't give you high availability and in case of a random shutdown your service will be down.

I would advise running the server on multiple one-core machines than on one multiple-core machine.
In order to do so, setup [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)/[forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) on each machine and another machine for running nginx for load balancing.

This [article](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) should get you started with nginx.